# Html "Already defined" Error

Tags: html, css

I am debugging a layout right now and have come across some strange errors. and I am serving the page up as DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict.

The error shows is like this

1. ID "OFFICENAME" already defined:

   div class="office" id="officename"
2. ID "OFFICENAME" first defined here

   span id="officename">

and

1. NET-enabling start-tag requires SHORTTAG YES

This error is showing in the break code

```
<br />
```

Please any one help me out of this and tell me the correct way of representing

Answer (score 4):

1. `id` must be unique. You can't have two elements with the same ID. You should remove one of the `id`s or use `class` instead. You can have multiple classes on any given element, e.g.:

   ```
   class="office officename"
   ```
2. In HTML/SGML meaning of `/` is different than in XHTML: `<foo/bar/` is `<foo>bar</foo>` and `<foo/>` is `<foo></foo>&gt;` (that's an archaic quirk supported only by W3C validator).
   You're probably sending XHTML markup as HTML. Use `text/html` MIME type with HTML5 DOCTYPE instead (you'll get better compatiblity, better validation and `/>` talismans will be allowed).

   ```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
   ```

Answer (score 2):

You can't have multiple elements with the same id. Change the id on the span or the div to something else.